# Can’t access E:\Windows>

Tags: windows-10, command-line, boot

Trying to follow the instructions on this video - https://youtu.be/LwK4Zkp0AQM - but I’m having an issue at the step at 4:05, when I access E:\ and input cd windows, I’m getting “the system cannot find the specified path” and can’t get through to E:\Windows>
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does that folder exist in your system?

Comment: The linked video has a duration of 3:26, therefore 4:05 is not a valid time. Have you linked the correct video?

Comment: Just changed the link - thanks for the heads up! Also, I’m not sure if it’s a folder

Comment: "Windows" as in your command has to be a folder in drive E:\. If such folder doesn't exist in that drive then obviously it won't "find the specified path". Please note that in the video that was the drive the user found out, it can be and likely is different on yours. Furthermore the whole thing seems to be way over the level of an user who doesn't understand this basic concept. What exactly are you trying to do? Why are you following this specific instructions?

Comment: Try opening `C:\Windows`(`cd C:\Windows`).